# Combining Excel data - 1 cell for conditioning and 1 cell for the actual data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using Excel 2010

1. First, I have 2 cells. The first cell indicates the color in text - Red Orange Green Grey. The second cell also contains plain text. The data is exported from a SharePoint list.
2. I want to combine those in to one cell. The red will just be that color of the cell, and with the plain text in the second cell inside.

What should I do? Any formula for suggestion

[image: picure of example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cell value can be a simple formula, but to do cell formatting you need to use either conditional formatting or VBA.

The cell formula would be: C2: `=B2`

The conditional formatting would be a formula looking at the cells in column A. You would need one formula per color. You would apply the formula to the range of cells in column C.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I should upvote for a good answer, or downvote for the very obviously incorrect red. ;)

Comment: That's my 'too lazy to change the color palette red' ... I just don't like the bright red.